# Jackson JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL is not working with custom serialiser

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a custom serialiser which extends `JsonSerializer<T>`
and in the `ObjectMapper` I have included `setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`.

I still see `null` field in response.

Currently, I ignore them by checking `null` for each property. I have almost 15 objects and it's very difficult to add `null` checking to each property. Object I am using is shared  by my applications, that is the reason why I am using custom serialiser to name the properties

```
@Override
public void serialize(Person personBean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
   if(personBean.getFirstName() != null){
      jgen.writeStringField("firstname", personBean.getFirstName() );
   }

   //etc...
}
```

How to avoid `null` check for each property and implement some generic code to avoid `null` values in my serialised response.

Comment: Can you post the line which shows that you have added `ObjectMapper` to include `NOT_NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when we write custom serialiser we need to take care about `null` values by ourself. To make it at least a little bit better we can add new `writeStringField` method and use it. For example:

```
class PersonJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        writeStringField(gen, "firstname", value.getFirstName());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private void writeStringField(JsonGenerator gen, String fieldName, String value) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            gen.writeStringField(fieldName, value);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to change only property names you can use [`PropertyNamingStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) option. There is a few possibilities like:

1. [LOWER_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#LOWER_CASE) - Naming convention in which all words of the logical name are in lower case, and no separator is used between words.
2. [KEBAB_CASE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html#KEBAB_CASE) - Naming convention used in languages like Lisp, where words are in lower-case letters, separated by hyphens.
3. For more check documentation

Example `ObjectMapper` customisation could look like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE);
```

If there is no predefined strategy which satisfies your need you can use [`JsonView`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) annotation.